# How to manage Multiple Databases and for One Model in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have one Single SQLalchemy Model Called `Articles` but i want to have different databases for each country

For example `usa_database`, `de_database`  and so on.

How to achive this with sqlalchemy?

For Example:

the model

```
class Article(base_model):
   __tablename__ = 'articles'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   article_name = Column(String(50))
```

if user Browse from Usa i want to get article table in the `usa_database`

and if the aurther write article to USA the article stores in the `usa_database`

and all the databases share the same Model

Comment: Please, present a sample you want to reach it.

Comment: Do you really mean separate *databases* or do you mean separate *tables* in the same database (a.k.a "catalog")?

Comment: my project is a large magazine Provide a different Content to Different Countries I want to Separate Every Country Content to It's Own Database